# Reading 2D array from .txt file in java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

there is an issue in data.txt we have 4 rows and 3 cols and gives me error out of bound kindly someone solve this but when I pass 4x4 in rows and cols it works well but it didnt meet project requirement

```
public class ReadMagicSquare {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt")));
      int rows = 4;
      int columns = 3;
      int [][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
      while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
         for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) {
               myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
            }
         }
      }
      
      for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<myArray.length;j++){
              System.out.print(myArray[i][j]+" ");
          }
          System.out.println();
      }
        
    }
    
}
```

in data.txt file

```
2 -1 1
6 4 24
2 19 7
```

Comment: It seems to be this: `for(int j=0;j<myArray.length;j++)`-> `for(int j=0;j<myArray[i].length;j++)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<myArray.length;j++){
              System.out.print(myArray[i][j]+" ");
          }
          System.out.println();
}
```

`myArray.length` gives you the number of rows in the 2D array, so in the inner loop, j would go from `0 to less than 4` instead of `0 to less than 3`, which would give you an out of bound error.

You need to iterate j from 0 to the number of columns.

Comment: damn it work thankyou

Comment: @MuhammadAli Sure thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where it calculates the **dimensions** of the matrix in the file, **read** it from the file and **construct** the matrix and **prints** it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("data.txt"));
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File("data.txt"));

    /*To get the dimension of the matrix*/
    String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
    int row = 1, column = 0;
    column=line.length;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        row++;
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    sc.close();

    /*To read the matrix*/
    int[][] matrix = new int[row][column];
    for(int r=0;r<row;r++) {
        for(int c=0;c<column;c++) {
            if(inFile.hasNextInt()) {
                matrix[r][c]=inFile.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    /*To print the matrix*/
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
}
```